# Save Bot Framework conversation and images offline using Node JS

Tags: node.js, botframework, azure-cosmosdb

I am building a chatbot using Node JS and the MS Bot Framework. I can take a picture within the chat client and display it as follows:

```
builder.Prompts.attachment(session, "Upload a picture for me to transform.", {

retryPrompt: 'The value you entered is not a valid picture. Please try again:',

maxRetries: 2 });
```

Is there any way I can save the picture taken to a storage account such as Azure?

Comment: Not really sure what you're asking. What do you mean, by wanting to save images to Cosmos? You want to store binary data in Cosmos?

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear. I've reworded my question to make it clearer. Put simply, how do I save the conversation, including any images taken by the user, offline in Cloud storage?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The bot is a server-side web application built with [Restify](http://restify.com/). [Connect your application to a database](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/) and upload your images to it like you would any normal web app. The specific implementation will depend on your choice of database technology and/or ORM adaptor.